# Links to profiles when @replying

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page

So when you do @User, it does notify the user, but I'd appreciate it if it became a link to their profile automatically, which can also be turned off as you type it. i.e. when you do the @ symbol, someones name comes up in a box. Next to that name we could have a "do not link" if they don't wanna link the profile.

Sort of like facebook.

Edit: i'd say this is partially duplicate.

The people in that question believe that this won't work. I suggest, in the suggestion box that comes up when you type @, there can be a list of the usernames. e.g. when you do @RegisteredUser, there are a bunch of Registered User names so just list them with profile pictures so the user can select which one. All of this is in the box where normally the site would suggest the name you're about to tag.

Comment: @random thanks, couldn't find it by search