# Badge in dupehammer tooltip should link to the badge page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tooltips, dupehammer

I just noticed the tooltip for dupehammer closure has been extended to show the relevant tag, and provide extra information: (seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267512/links-to-profiles-when-replying), you need to click the golden tag)

> [image]

This is awesome, and the tag is indeed a link to the tag page, however the badge is not a link. Can the badge please also be a link, to the specific badge page, e.g. in the above example [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/45/feature-request)?

Comment: Why? How does the tag page help the author of the post understand why it's closed, or what they should do to get it reopened? Links are great if they point to some helpful information; otherwise they are noise.

Comment: @Mice the tag itself is a "built in" popup that exists all over the place. What I request is link to the badge page showing list of users with the badge, so that OP will know who else might use that power. It can't be noise since it doesn't add anything, not even a single pixel, to the contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're completing a bit of work on this (see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/), so this is all largely still subject to change.

I could see this request making sense from a consistency standpoint if we make the popup show on hover over and let users clickthrough to the badge.

I'll mark this [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for now.

**Edit by Jarrod**

Gold tag badges are now linked and the popup message is now on hover.

Comment: @Jarrod found a bug. When I hover over it, the popup appears, while it used to appear on click before. That's still fine, but when I hover away the popup vanish - even if I hover into it. Can you please look into it?

Comment: That's kinda by design - nothing is supposed to be clickable in the popup.  Is the gold tag badge not a large enough hover target?

Comment: Well, this is not what I meant then. I kind of liked the popup being on its own like a tag popup, and being able to click the tag for example inside the popup. Anyway, can't deny this serves the purpose I had in mind, so thanks!